Points on geometry measurement
I want to do points on polygon of 30 metres interval but the distance keeps measuring degrees instead of meters. How do I change the degrees to meters?

Which CRS is your project and polygon layer in?

EPSG 4326 WGS84

Then reproject the layer to a fitting local meter-based CRS - most likely your UTM-zone and try again.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no one simple equation to accurately convert between angular quantities (degrees) and planar units (meters) everywhere. This is why projections exist. There's a learning curve involved, though, and it extends for several chapters in intro texts, which makes this Question rather broad.
